# What advantages does Armory have over Bitcoin-Qt?

Tags: bitcoin-core, armory

What advantages does Armory have over Bitcoin-Qt? Just better multisig support? Armory runs `bitcoind`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some obvious reasons:

- Deterministic wallet (only need to store the seed, bitcoind's wallet uses a random number per address).
- Multisig support with lockboxes.
- Paper backups with SecurePrint.
- Fragmented backups (you need m of n pieces to get back your wallet)
- Offline signing for additional security

There's also a lot more features that are on the way that we'll be announcing (Disclosure: I work for Armory)